# RegEx for validating scientific notations

Tags: python, regex, scientific-notation

I am trying to find out if a number is represented using scientific notation. I already tested my regex pattern with valid/invalid test cases using online regex tool. However, when I use use my regex pattern in python, it doesn't match some valid test cases.

Here is the regex pattern:

```
^-?([1-9]{1}|[1-9]?\.[0-9]+)[eE][+\-]?0?[1-9]+0*$
```

valid test cases:

```
-9.99E+9
9E-1
1e-12
1e12
1e-06
1e-066
1e6000
4.2e06
4.2e-06
4.2e60
.1e12
3.2e23
-4.70e+9
-.2E-4
4e6666
4e6660
4e-6666
```

invalid test cases:

```
37.e88 
1.2e001
10e1
0.0e12
-0.9e2
-9e-0
0e12
9.3e0.2
0e000
1e00009
1e00090
1e000
1
1.000
e112
45e12
0.1e12
```

but if I try in python:

```py
pat = re.compile('^-?([1-9]{1}|[1-9]?\.[0-9]+)[eE][+\-]?0?[1-9]+0*$')
match = re.search(pat, str(4.2e6))
```

it returns None. this is a valid test case. Also, 4.2e06, 4.2e666, 4.2e-66 are all valid test cases but it returns None. why does it work for online regex tool but not python regex engine?

I looked at some stackoverflow posts and tried answers given there such as:
pat = re.compile(r'^[+-]?(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:.\d*)?(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)$')

It doesn't work for 4.2e06, 4.2e666, 4.2e-66.

Comment: link for those who want to test this: https://regex101.com/r/QFFidh/1

Comment: Here's a hint: Go to a Python prompt (the one with the `>>>` at the beginning of the line) and try to see what `str(4.2e6)` is.

Comment: @JohnY oh wow!! that's crazy. The reason I have str() is because python kept complaining "expected string or bytes-like object". I thought it would keep it as is and am not sure why it does a conversion to float and then store it as string.

Comment: What do you mean, "conversion to float"? `4.2e6` is a float. `str()` then converts it to a string. If you wanted a string, you should've probably used `"4.2e6"` in the first place.

Comment: @melpomene i meant keep it in scientific notation. for ex, str(4.2e-6) stays as it is. I have only posted an example. originally, I have a numpy array of floats and I am trying to detect a number with scientific notation within the array. Hence, the use of str()

Comment: I dont get you why you try to have regex on floats? In logic its made for strings or texts, not trim or find values in integers or floats

Comment: Why do you want to detect which elements are displayed in scientific notation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fix your match search by

```
match = re.search(pat, '4.2e6')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this

`(?m)^[+-]?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)$`

https://regex101.com/r/oLA3hH/1